# Flatten a Series in pandas, i.e. a series whose elements are lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

I have a series of the form:

```
s = Series([['a','a','b'],['b','b','c','d'],[],['a','b','e']])
```

which looks like

```
0       [a, a, b]
1    [b, b, c, d]
2              []
3       [a, b, e]
dtype: object
```

I would like to count how many elements I have in total.
My naive tentatives like

```
s.values.hist()
```

or

```
s.values.flatten()
```

didn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remember that `Series` and `DataFrames` aren't really meant to contain lists; you can do it, but you lose easy access to a lot of the nice features.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good advice. But what if the date are list indexed by elements, like in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s.map(len).sum()
```

does the trick. `s.map(len)` applies `len()` to each element and returns a series of all the lengths, then you can just use `sum` on that series.

Comment: True thanks! What if I want to have a histogram with the distributions of each letter?

Comment: You can do a quick version of that with `import collections; s.map(collections.Counter).sum()`. Read up on `collections.Counter` if you haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 16):

If we stick with the pandas Series as in the original question, one neat option from the Pandas version 0.25.0 onwards is the [Series.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) routine. It returns an exploded list to rows, where the index will be duplicated for these rows.

The original Series from the question:

```
s = pd.Series([['a','a','b'],['b','b','c','d'],[],['a','b','e']])
```

Let's explode it and we get a Series, where the index is repeated. The index indicates the index of the original list.

```
>>> s.explode()
Out:
0      a
0      a
0      b
1      b
1      b
1      c
1      d
2    NaN
3      a
3      b
3      e
dtype: object

>>> type(s.explode())
Out:
pandas.core.series.Series
```

**To count the number of elements we can now use the Series.value_counts():**

```
>>> s.explode().value_counts()
Out:
b    4
a    3
d    1
c    1
e    1
dtype: int64
```

To include also NaN values:

```
>>> s.explode().value_counts(dropna=False)
Out:
b      4
a      3
d      1
c      1
e      1
NaN    1
dtype: int64
```

**Finally, plotting the histogram using Series.plot():**

```
>>> s.explode().value_counts(dropna=False).plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image: Histogram of the Series]

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
word_lists=[['apple','orange'],['red','yellow']]
vocab=list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(raw_data.word_lists)))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I *love* having arrays in dataframes, for every single item a single column. It will give you much more functionality. So, here's my alternative approach

```
>>> raw = [['a', 'a', 'b'], ['b', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [], ['a', 'b', 'e']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(raw)
>>> df
Out[217]: 
      0     1     2     3
0     a     a     b  None
1     b     b     c     d
2  None  None  None  None
3     a     b     e  None
```

Now, see how many values we have in each row

```
>>> df.count(axis=1)
Out[226]: 
0    3
1    4
2    0
3    3
```

Applying `sum()` here would give you what you wanted.

Second, what you mentioned in a comment: get the distribution. There may be a cleaner approach here, but I still prefer the following over the hint that was given you in the comment

```
>>> foo = [col.value_counts() for x, col in df.iteritems()]
>>> foo
Out[246]: 
[a    2
 b    1
 dtype: int64, b    2
 a    1
 dtype: int64, b    1
 c    1
 e    1
 dtype: int64, d    1
 dtype: int64]
```

`foo` contains distribution for every column now. The interpretation of columns is still "xth value", such that column 0 contains the distribution of all the "first values" in your arrays.

Next step, "sum them up".

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(foo)
>>> df2
Out[266]: 
    a   b   c   d   e
0   2   1 NaN NaN NaN
1   1   2 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN   1   1 NaN   1
3 NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN
>>> test.sum(axis=0)
Out[264]: 
a    3
b    4
c    1
d    1
e    1
dtype: float64
```

Note that for these very simple problems the difference between a series of lists and a dataframe with columns per item is not big, but once you want to do *real* data work, the latter gives you *way* more functionality. Moreover, it can potentially be more efficient, since you can use pandas internal methods.

Comment: This is also very useful. Actually in my lists I have links (from a crawler), so there are no duplicates. I will definitely try this approach. It also seems more natural